# php Amazon S3 PutObject access denied

Tags: php, amazon-s3

The problem is common, but I can't solved. Screenshot of the error attached. Full bucket rights do not help. I do not know what the solution to this problem can be. In extreme cases, just recommend an alternative to the Amazon S3.

[S3 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmyeM.jpg)

Comment: alternative https://cloudinary.com

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please paste the error in your question, do not link to an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear from the screenshot. There is a time difference between your server and S3, which is causing a failure. Fix the time on your server and try again.